# how to change windows Identity in window service and send the identity to a webclient in C#

Tags: c#, windows-services, asp.net-web-api2

I have Window service which will read a some data from a table and post the data to a webapi service. Data Stored in this table is user based.

my thought process:

- I will get the userid and set the current identity in window service to that userid.
- The webapi can get the same identity details on request.
- The current identity changes, but the request identity still goes as the default window service system identity.

Sample that i tried for httpget

```
GenericIdentity identity = new GenericIdentity("Test1"); //userfromDB
System.Threading.Thread.CurrentPrincipal =  new GenericPrincipal(identity,new string[] { "Role1", "Roll2" });                    


var webClient = new WebClient()
        {UseDefaultCredentials = true,};
var response =  webClient.DownloadStringTaskAsync("http://url/api/controller");
```

Is this possible or is there a better approach to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

I would think that this is not possible because it could be a huge security hole by nefarious applications.

I would recommend using a token for authentication/authorization.

1. Using a Bearer token like a JWT would make your API more open to other platforms.
2. Network performance would probably be better.  For example, with NTLM there are at least three HTTP request/response messages to authenticate the Windows user before the first API call is made.